# Как получить побитовое И другим способом?

Tags: алгоритм

Как для двух целых чисел `a` и `b` получить побитовое И `a & b` без непосредственного использования этого оператора?

Comment: Быстрее напишите кто-нибудь ответ - человек, может быть, сейчас на экзамене!

Comment: А у вас профессор не отобрал телефон? Значит, будет ещё устная часть экзамена. Удачи вам.

Comment: @VladD, имеет смысл вопрос править, или нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще можно было бы, если убрать информацию про экзамен и оставить только вопрос про И без &

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я бы взялся за вопрос через пару часов, не раньше. Во имя высшей справедливости.

Comment: @Grundy: Но раз уж человек подставился...

Comment: Мне кажется, имелось в виду описать через деление/умножение на 2 и ифы. Типичное учебное задание на понимание, бессмысленное и беспощадное.

Comment: @VladD, вопрос-то в общем-то интересный. Мой ответ на уровне "если понимает что-нибудь, то напишет сам". На мой взгляд, только в качестве вопроса проблема.

Comment: @VladD, а такой способ я что-то не придумал.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, табличку истинности же им давали. Вот и вопрос на её применение.

Comment: @VladD, целые числа и побитовый оператор. Не просчитывать же каждый бит отдельно? С `bool` всё было бы совсем просто.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, поксорить xor с или:

```
(a^b)^(a|b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Два часа прошли :)

Отрицание от побитового ИЛИ отрицаний. На C

```
~(~a|~b)
```